# Corda: Update and consume ContractState in a single transaction

Tags: corda

### Problem

Consider the following design problem in Corda. Suppose that I have a `ContractState`, say `Order`, which carries an explicit status, for instance its either `ALIVE` or `CANCELED`. The latter status relates to *finished* orders. I would like to have a transaction which takes a single, `ALIVE` input state `Order` and consumes it **while changing its status to `CANCELED`**. Can I have an atomic transition accomplishing this task? In other words, is it possible to record the reason why a state was consumed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Anytime a state is added as an input to a transaction, it is considered consumed.
- Let's say `Order` has 3 attributes: `Order(linearId, status, reason)`.
- To mimic updates in Corda, your transaction will take as an input the state to be updated; and produce a new state that has the same `linearId` but with different values for the remaining attributes. This way all states in your vault that have the same `linearId` are considered different versions of the same state, there will be only one `UNCONSUMED` version; which is the latest version.
- `Order(123, ALIVE, null)` ---Update Tx---> `Order(123, CANCELED, "No longer needed")`.
- You might also consider not creating an output if the state is "canceled"; you just consume it and not create an output; meaning it no longer exists on the ledger and Corda doesn't track it: `Order(123, ALIVE, null)` ---Cancel Tx---> no output.

Comment: Thank you! I knew both these solutions before asking the question. I wanted to be sure that there's essentially nothing more idiomatic.